# KnockoutJS - Setting Select Menu Based on Selection in another Menu

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have two `<select>` menus and a textbox. When an option in the first menu is selected, it should update the value in the textbox and it should also set the selected option in the 2nd select menu.

The textbox updates correctly.

However, the 2nd select menu is not updated.

The `ParentID` value from the first menu should be used to specify the `TaskID` value of the second menu. The `ParentID` value is a FK reference to `TaskID` in the same table.

For example, in the below, if *"ManualItems"* is selected in the first menu, then *"Positions"* should become the value selected in the 2nd menu.

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables
    self.currentTask = ko.observable();
    self.selectedParentTask = ko.observable();
    self.taskDescription = ko.observable("");
   
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([
        {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", TaskDescription: "Manual Rec", ParentID: 4, ParentName: "Positions"},
        {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", TaskDescription: "Trades Data", ParentID: null, ParentName: null},
        {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "File-In", TaskDescription: "File Detail", ParentID: 2, ParentName: "Trades"},
        {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Positions", TaskDescription: "Positions Overview", ParentID: null, ParentName: null}
    ]);
    
    self.parentTasks = ko.observableArray([
        {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", TaskDescription: "Manual Rec", ParentID: 4, ParentName: "Positions"},
        {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", TaskDescription: "Trades Data", ParentID: null, ParentName: null},
        {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "File-In", TaskDescription: "File Detail", ParentID: 2, ParentName: "Trades"},
        {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Positions", TaskDescription: "Positions Overview", ParentID: null, ParentName: null}
    ]);
    
    /*
    self.currentTask.subscribe(function(newValue){
      self.selectedParentTask(newValue);
    });
    */
    
    self.EditTask = function () {
        // populate all fields with selected task
        self.taskDescription(self.currentTask().TaskDescription);
        self.selectedParentTask(self.currentTask()); // set parent task to the ParentID value of currentTask
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskName">Edit Existing Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskNameSelect" data-bind="
        options: tasks,
        optionsText: 'TaskName',
        value: currentTask,
        event: {change: $root.EditTask},
        optionsCaption: 'Select Task...'
    "></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskParent">Select Parent Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskParent" data-bind="
        options: parentTasks,
        optionsText: 'TaskName',
        value: selectedParentTask,
        optionsCaption: 'Select Parent Task...'
    "></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskDescription">Task Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="taskDescription" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Task Description" data-bind="value: taskDescription"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1600/) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, avoid setting DOM event handlers in knockout. Most of the time you can do the same with less code and less ambiguity by using subscriptions.

In this case you want to react to changes in the `currentTask` by finding the matching parent task for it.

`ko.utils.arrayFirst()` is a handy [utility function](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) that pulls out the first element from an array that matches a certain condition. (Nowadays you can also use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for the same effect.)

So, we get:

```
self.currentTask.subscribe(function (task) {
    var matchingParentTask = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.parentTasks(), function (parent) {
        return parent.TaskName === task.ParentName;
    });
    self.parentTask(matchingParentTask);
    self.taskDescription(task.TaskDescription);
});
```

And in context:

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables
    self.currentTask = ko.observable();
    self.parentTask = ko.observable();
    self.taskDescription = ko.observable();
   
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([
        {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", TaskDescription: "Manual Rec", ParentID: 4, ParentName: "Positions"},
        {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", TaskDescription: "Trades Data", ParentID: null, ParentName: null},
        {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "File-In", TaskDescription: "File Detail", ParentID: 2, ParentName: "Trades"},
        {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Positions", TaskDescription: "Positions Overview", ParentID: null, ParentName: null}
    ]);
    
    self.parentTasks = ko.observableArray([
        {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", TaskDescription: "Manual Rec", ParentID: 4, ParentName: "Positions"},
        {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", TaskDescription: "Trades Data", ParentID: null, ParentName: null},
        {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "File-In", TaskDescription: "File Detail", ParentID: 2, ParentName: "Trades"},
        {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Positions", TaskDescription: "Positions Overview", ParentID: null, ParentName: null}
    ]);
    
    self.currentTask.subscribe(function (task) {
        var matchingParentTask = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.parentTasks(), function (parent) {
            return parent.TaskName === task.ParentName;
        });
        self.parentTask(matchingParentTask);
        self.taskDescription(task.TaskDescription);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskName">Edit Existing Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskNameSelect" data-bind="
        value: currentTask,
        options: tasks,
        optionsText: 'TaskName',
        optionsCaption: 'Select Task...'
    "></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskParent">Select Parent Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskParent" data-bind="
        value: parentTask,
        options: parentTasks,
        optionsText: 'TaskName',
        optionsCaption: 'Select Parent Task...'
    "></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskDescription">Task Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="taskDescription" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Task Description" data-bind="value: taskDescription"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Since you want to build a task editor, I think you will get a lot further with this: https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1601/ than with what the answer above shows. Compare closely, none of what we did above (or what you have asked for in this question) is really necessary if you use knockout right.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of relations can often be implemented using `ko.computed` properties that specify a `read` and `write` method.

The computed's `read` property points to an observable private to the viewmodel that stores the "current selection".

The `write` methods define *how a new value not only sets the underlying observable, but also its **side effects** on any other properties*.

Applying this to your first dropdown, which writes to `self.currentTask`:

- `read` references the "private" observable that stores the selection:

  ```
  read: current,
  ```
- `write` eventually stores the new selection:

  ```
  write: function(task) {
    /* ... */
    current(task)
  }
  ```
- but before writing, it checks if there's a matching parent task:

  ```
  if (task && task.ParentID) {
    // Find parent task with right ID
    var curParent = self.parentTasks()
      .find(function(parent) {
        return parent.TaskID === task.ParentID;
      });

    // If it's there, write to parent selection
    if (curParent) {
      parent(curParent);
    }
  }
  ```

In implementing these computeds, you'll also notice you haven't completely defined your desired relationship/user interaction.

Questions that remain:

- What if a task has a `null` parent?
- What if a user overwrites the value of the parent drop down?

In a working example, without the undefined behaviors:

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  
  var current = ko.observable(null);
  var parent = ko.observable(null);
  
  self.tasks = ko.observableArray(tasks());
  self.parentTasks = ko.observableArray(parentTasks());

  self.currentTask = ko.computed({
    read: current,
    write: function(task) {
      if (task && task.ParentID) {
        // Find parent task with right ID
        var curParent = self.parentTasks()
          .find(function(parent) {
            return parent.TaskID === task.ParentID;
          });
          
        // If it's there, write to parent selection
        if (curParent) {
          parent(curParent);
        }
      }
      
      current(task);
    }
  });
  
  self.parentTask = ko.computed({
    read: parent,
    write: function(task) {
      /* To be filled in by the question asker */
      parent(task);
    }
  });
  

  // This can be automated via a `computed`:
  self.taskDescription = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var current = self.currentTask();
    var parent = self.parentTask();
    
    return (current ? current.TaskDescription : "no existing task") +
      " - (" +
      (parent ? parent.TaskDescription : "no parent task") +
      ")";
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());



function tasks() {
  return [
    {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", TaskDescription: "Manual Rec", ParentID: 4, ParentName: "Positions"},
    {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", TaskDescription: "Trades Data", ParentID: null, ParentName: null},
    {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "File-In", TaskDescription: "File Detail", ParentID: 2, ParentName: "Trades"},
    {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Positions", TaskDescription: "Positions Overview", ParentID: null, ParentName: null}
  ];
};

function parentTasks() {
  return [
    {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", TaskDescription: "Manual Rec", ParentID: 4, ParentName: "Positions"},
    {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", TaskDescription: "Trades Data", ParentID: null, ParentName: null},
    {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "File-In", TaskDescription: "File Detail", ParentID: 2, ParentName: "Trades"},
    {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Positions", TaskDescription: "Positions Overview", ParentID: null, ParentName: null}
  ];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskName">Edit Existing Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskNameSelect"
            data-bind="options: tasks,
                                optionsText: 'TaskName',
                                value: currentTask,
                                optionsCaption: 'Select Task...'"></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskParent">Select Parent Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskParent"
            data-bind="options: parentTasks,
                                optionsText: 'TaskName',
                                value: parentTask,
                                optionsCaption: 'Select Parent Task...'"></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskDescription">Task Description</label>
    <p class="form-control" data-bind="text: taskDescription"></p>
</div>
```